# How to make sqlalchemy return float instead of Decimal when reflecting tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL database that has been defined outside of my Python code.  I'm using reflection to get it into SQLAlchemy, so I don't have any class definitions I can modify.  I don't have to worry about losing precision, and I do some arithmetic with the results in Python, so I'd rather not have to manually convert a bunch of values to either float or Decimal.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

eng = sa.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@server/database")
eng.execute("create table if not exists foo (x double not null)")
eng.execute("insert into foo (x) values (0.1)")

md = sa.MetaData(bind=eng)
md.reflect()
foo = md.tables["foo"]

res = eng.execute(foo.select())
row = res.fetchone()
print(type(row.x))
print(repr(foo.c.x.type))
```

Output:

```
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
DOUBLE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the suggestion from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/3DK9UqolonE/discussion), and not using the reflected tables until I set the `asdecimal` attribute, I can get floats instead of Decimals.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

eng = sa.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://chiptest:fryisthedevil@database/bench_drylake")
eng.execute("create table if not exists foo (x double not null)")
eng.execute("insert into foo (x) values (0.1)")

md = sa.MetaData(bind=eng)
md.reflect()
foo = md.tables["foo"]

# this needs to happen before any queries
for table in md.tables.values():
    for column in table.columns.values():
        if isinstance(column.type, sa.Numeric):
            column.type.asdecimal = False

res = eng.execute(foo.select())
row = res.fetchone()
print(type(row.x))
print(repr(foo.c.x.type))
```

Output:

```
<class 'float'>
DOUBLE(asdecimal=False)
```

Note:  If you do a query on the reflected table before setting `asdecimal = False`, `column.type` still shows up as `DOUBLE(asdecimal=False)`, but the type of the value is still `Decimal`.  I'm guessing this is because SQLAlchemy is doing some sort of caching, but I'm not going to figure this out for sure right now.

Comment: For working inside of a `SQLAlchemy` Model, you would just do something like this: https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/f7fd9184a1950912d0ea

Comment: @dennismonsewicz you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Worker It's not technically an answer to this question, though it is definitely related and could be useful for someone searching for this.