# Pandas reporting series to be an object when it's a decimal

Tags: python, pandas, types

I need an automated reliable way to find the data type of each column in a pandas data frame. I have been using .dtype() but have noticed something unexpected with it.

Consider this 10 row data frame:

```
df['a']
Out[6]: 
0    250.00
1    750.00
2      0.00
3      0.00
4      0.00
5      0.00
6      0.00
7      0.00
8      0.00
9      0.00
Name: a, dtype: object

type(df['a'][0])
Out[9]: decimal.Decimal
```

Why is the dtype of the entire column an 'object' when each entry is a decimal? I really need it to say decimal or float or something numeric. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Decimal` is not a principle numpy `dtype` so it's represented as an `object` but the actual cell type is still `Decimal`, this is also what happens for `date` and `str` objects for example, this is correct behaviour. If you don't need decimal precision then you can use `float64`. This https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html demonstrates the `dytpe` hierarchy. The reason to prefer the supported types is that vectorised operations will be supported but they may not be for others, even though they may well be numerical

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an error but is due to the `numpy` `dtype` representation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html.

Basically as `Decimal` is not a principle inbuilt type then it's dtype ends up being `object` even though the actual type of each cell is still `Decimal`.

It's advised where possible to use the inbuilt scalar types, in this case `float64`, because arithmetic operations are unlikely to be vectorised even though the type may well be numerical.

The same is observed when you store `str` or `datetime.date` values, the dtype is `object` for these.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Is there any function that would return decimal/float64 if I inputted the pandas column?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand if the dtype is float64 it returns float64, if it's decimal it returns object. What do you mean by return decimal/float64? you mean the metadata or the value?

Comment: I would like a function that would return something that indicates that it is numeric if it is a decimal. I have a df with >200 columns and I need to identify the type each column is. As the dtype function also returns 'object' for columns which are strings I have no way of differentiating between a column which is a string and a decimal.

Comment: So the question is why use `Decimal` if `float64` does what you want? Where does this data come from? How are you adding columns with decimal in the first place, your question lacks context here. Personally if you don't need decimal and you can't modify how the data is inserted then call `pd.to_numeric` on the decimal columns

Comment: The data is coming from an API. I could modify the columns that are decimal but how will I know which ones are decimal and which ones are strings when pandas tells me that they are both 'objects'? I could check the first few elements of the series but I was hoping for a less hacky way :)

Comment: There is no built-in method to filter the columns when the dtype is `object`, you'd need to iterate over the object columns and test every first value for the real dtype and then convert, are you able to modify the api or convert on assignment? It's strongly advised to use the built-in scalar types when using pandas otherwise you run into issues like this which invalidates the purpose the pandas. I can post code to show how you could filter it but's nothing more than a loop

Comment: I suppose the hacky was is the only way which I can figure out how to do :) thanks

Comment: basically you'd need to do `df.select_dtypes([np.object]).iloc[0]` and test each value for it's real dtype and store the column name, and then `apply` `pd.to_numeric` to convert to `float64`

Comment: Here's a good way to automatically fix this for all columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387883/2440

Comment: @Sire I think that solution is only relevant for SQL data types, there is a python `Decimal` dtype that isn't a native numpy dtype which is what this addresses