# Applying function to columns of a Pandas DataFrame, conditional on data type

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the common pattern to apply a function to every column in a Pandas DataFrame, but the function should work conditional on the column data type.

Sounds simple enough. But I found a weird behavior in testing for the data type and I cannot find anywhere in the docs or googling the reason for it.

Consider this repex:

```
import pandas as pd

toydf = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A = [1, 2, 3],
    B = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    C = ['1', '2', '3'],
    D = [True, True, False]
))
```

Checking individually the dtypes they are `dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('O'), dtype('bool')`

But if I use the `apply` function, all columns passed to the function are `dtype: object`.

```
def dtype_fn(the_col):
    print(the_col)
    return(the_col.dtype)

toydf.apply(dtype_fn)

toydf.apply(dtype_fn)
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: object
0    1.1
1    1.2
2    1.3
Name: B, dtype: object
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: C, dtype: object
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: D, dtype: object
Out[167]: 
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
```

Why is this?, what I am doing wrong?, why the columns does not retain the original data types?

Here's an approach that works and produced my desired output: (but for encapsulation reasons, I don't like it)

```
def dtype_fn2(col_name):
    return(toydf[col_name].dtype)

[dtype_fn2(col) for col in toydf.columns]

Out[173]: [dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('O'), dtype('bool')]
```

Comment: After doing some more reading, what happens is that when you do the apply over those columns, since multiple columns of different type are in question here, pandas will choose the "common denominator" among those columns.

In your example, if you remove the "string" and "boolean" columns, you will stop getting "object" as your type and get float64.

That being said, I don't know a way around this, and I learned something new today thanks to this adventure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180132/applying-function-to-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-conditional-on-data-type#comment97104222_55180132) is correct. This behaviour is by design. Pandas "applies" the type that is highest up in the type hierarchy for all dtypes given.

Consider applying the function to only "A",

```
df[['A']].apply(dtype_fn)
int64

A    int64
dtype: object
```

And similarly, with only "A" and "B",

```
df[['A', 'B']].apply(dtype_fn)
float64
float64

A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Since you have multiple types, including string in your original DataFrame, the common type for them all is `object`.

---

Now this explains the behaviour, but I still need to address the fix. Pandas offers a useful method: [`Series.infer_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) which infers the dtype and performs a "soft conversion".

If you really need the type in the function, you can perform a soft cast before calling `dtype`. This produces the expected result:

```
def dtype_fn(the_col):
     the_col = the_col.infer_objects()
     print(the_col.dtype)

     return(the_col.dtype)
```

```
df.apply(dtype_fn)
int64
float64
object
bool

A      int64
B    float64
C     object
D       bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: cool, thx @coldspeed for introducing us to `Series.infer_objects` which indeed is a fix for my issue. I was not aware of this fn, but even if I had saw it, probably I would have not thought this was the fix. Given its name, I would have assumed it would have inferred column C to be dtype int64, 'cause it has only integers. But it turns out it is smart enough to realize this column was originally a string and appropriately returns an dtype: object, even though it has only integer values. Not sure why it is the case and how does it do it, so perhaps I will have to take a closer look at it. Thx !

Comment: @HernandoCasas Indeed, `infer_objects` does not parse values in the series to infer it type, but only checks the dtypes of each values and determines whether a scalar vectorizable dtype (int, float, datetime, etc) can be assigned, or object.

Comment: awesome, thx. Does checking the `dtype` of each value have a performance penalty? just wondering if it could be something similar to calling `mean` on a data frame vs. `mean(only numeric)`. I read recently that the former is much slower if there are string columns (object `dtype`), 'cause Pandas cannot know in advance the underlying data type (which may as well be a python numeric type; non-numpy though) and then it tries to calculate the mean anyway for object columns, and ends up concatenating string columns only to find out it cannot be divided by n and only then discards the column

Comment: @HernandoCasas if you are worried about performance, you can always just pass df.dtypes.to_dict() as an argument to the function when applying it...

Answer (score 2):

The actual input to your `dtype_fn` is a Pandas Series object. You can access the underlying type by modifying your method slightly.

```
def dtype_fn(the_col):
    print(the_col.values.dtype)
    return(the_col.values.dtype)
```

For more info about why this is the case, you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307792/pandas-reporting-series-to-be-an-object-when-its-a-decimal). There it says

> This is not an error but is due to the numpy dtype representation:
>   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the pointer to the other SO question. I have actually seen that answer, but I thought it was slightly different issue, since they are dealing with non-native numpy/pandas data types. In my case I am using built-in numpy/pandas data types. I tried your solution modifying the function to get dtype after getting the values, but I still get object dtype for what should have been int64 or float64.

Comment: and yes, the input to the function is a Pandas Series object. That's also why I thought simply getting the `the_col.dtype` should work. Because if I do it individually I would get the Pandas series object simply like `toydf["A"]`, whose **type** `type(toy["A"])` is indeed pandas.core.series.Series, but it's **dtype** `toy["A"].dtype` gives me the data type I am interested in (`int64`)

Comment: Hmm, yes you are correct. Strange, I was so sure that this would work I didn't even think of running it myself! I guess you taught me something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

You wish to use the apply fn on a dataframe however, you forgot about base typecasting ( an issue in most OOP languages). Quick fix is as follows:

```
def selectiveapply(row):
    return(type(row[0]))
toydf=toydf.T
toydf["type"]=toydf.apply(selectiveapply,axis=1)
```

apply can also be applied column-wise by setting axis=0. Toy around a bit with the functions and you'll reach your answer eventually.